# Python SQLite3 Back Up Parameters

Tags: python, sqlite, backup

I am new to SQLite and wondering how to create a backup for a database, on a similar site I have found a question on how to create a backup for a database but I am having problems getting it to work.

This is the question:https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/78643/create-sqlite-backups

This is the code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import argparse
import sqlite3
import shutil
import time
import os

NO_OF_DAYS = 7

def sqlite3_backup(dbfile, backupdir):

dbfile = Accounts.db
backupdir = r"E:\TESTING\BackUp.db"
"""Create timestamped database copy"""

if not os.path.isdir(backupdir):
    raise Exception("Backup directory does not exist: {}".format(backupdir))

backup_file = r"E:\TESTING\BackUp.db" + time.strftime("-%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

connection = sqlite3.connect(r"E:\TESTING\Accounts.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Lock database before making a backup
cursor.execute('begin immediate')
# Make new backup file
shutil.copyfile(dbfile, backup_file)
print ("\nCreating {}...".format(backup_file))
# Unlock database
connection.rollback()

def clean_data(backup_dir):

backup_dir = r"E:\TESTING\BackUp.db"

print ("\n------------------------------")
print ("Cleaning up old backups")

for filename in os.listdir(backup_dir):
    backup_file = os.path.join(backup_dir, filename)
    if os.stat(backup_file).st_ctime < (time.time() - NO_OF_DAYS * 86400):
        if os.path.isfile(backup_file):
            os.remove(backup_file)
            print ("Deleting {}...".format(ibackup_file))

def get_arguments():
##    connection = sqlite3.connect(r"E:\TESTING\Accounts.db")
##    cursor = connection.cursor()
backup_dir = r"E:\TESTING\BackUp.db"
db_file = sqlite3.connect(r"E:\TESTING\Accounts.db")
"""Parse the commandline arguments from the user"""

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('db_file',
                    help='the database file that needs backed up')
parser.add_argument('backup_dir',
                     help='the directory where the backup'
                          'file should be saved')
return parser.parse_args()

if __name__ == "__main__":
#args = get_arguments()
dbfile = Accounts
backup_dir = "E:\TESTING"
#sqlite3_backup(args.db_file, args.backup_dir)
sqlite3_backup(db_file, backup_dir)
clean_data(args.backup_dir)

print ("\nBackup update has been successful.")
```

When I run the code I get this error `usage: backup.py [-h] db_file backup_dir
backup.py: error: the following arguments are required: db_file, backup_dir`

I have subbed into the code the db_file and the backup_dir but it still appearing with the same error.

Comment: that script is not doing anything but creating a copy of the database file.
it takes 2 arguments <data base file name > < Backup Dir >

Comment: I understand that but do not know hot to attach a file when it is a argument in a function.

Comment: There are missing quotes in Accounts.db and Accounts (why are they different and why are you overwriting one with the other in the backup function?. Aren't they strings? Check the indentation of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change this part:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #args = get_arguments()
    dbfile = <<YOUR DB FILE NAME >>
    backup_dir = <<YOUR BACK UP DIRECTORY PATH>>
    #sqlite3_backup(args.db_file, args.backup_dir)
    sqlite3_backup(db_file, backup_dir)
    # CHANGE  clean_data(args.backup_dir)
    #TO: 
    clean_data(backup_dir)
    print ("\nBackup update has been successful.")
```

Comment: That appears with the error `    dbfile = Accounts
NameError: name 'Accounts' is not defined`

Comment: can your post your full code in the question. So i can be able to help.